# Stay foreground using notification , How?

Tags: java, android, service, notifications, foreground

From docs I understand that our program goes to background when we open another_one then after a while android will call onDestroy() to take back it's resources ; But our program is kind of watcher (imagine we have a mediaplyer which playes music in backGround) and it should not be closed until int programState == 1  (There is a power button which ends the player or watcher ) . Besides I learned that we can stay foreground with "Notification" which is so cool (But I don't know how) ! Here is a notification code:

```
 in  Activity's onCreate(){

       //> reading some data and define some initial values .


       mNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

       Notification app_notfiy =addNotification();

       //> still should perform somehing ?!?



}



   private Notification addNotification() {



   NotificationCompat.Builder builder =  
           new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)  
           .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_new)  
           .setContentTitle(getText(string.app_name))  
           .setContentText("> This is a notification !?")
           .setUsesChronometer(true)
           ;  

   Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);  
   PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,      notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);  
   builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);  


   return builder.build() ;

  }
```

But here we have 2 problems . First I don't think notification  is really attached to  Activity (Maybe it needs some permissions or use service not sure !? ) ! Next I want  notification to resume app not restart it !? (I think it starts activity  from onCreate() ) How force it back to where we were ?

I've searched alot but still couldn't find good answers about this . Any Idea ?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what's your use case here, but it sound like you're looking for Service.
http://thorbek.net/online/2013/10/16/mediaplayer-in-background/

Comment: @TomislavNovoselec : Good example . It might solve my problem . tanks.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you have to use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html).

You can start the service as a "foreground service", which runs in the background and will hardly ever get killed by the system.

To do this, call [`startForeground(id, notification)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)).